# How to fix Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' error?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Trying to make some webapp with java? spring and hibernate. I am noob in java.
Nake all by the manual, but getting error

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in dev.test.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

My HibernateConfig.Java

```
package dev.test.config;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "dev.test")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/db.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("dev.test.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

In DAO file just add

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Before this changes? when i try to make app with temporary storage(just dict in app) all work.
Would be very glad for any help.

Comment: `Hibernate` is not on the deployed classpath.

Comment: Thabk you for your help, but can you tell me what should i change to make Hibernate be in classpath? I am very noob, so if you would be more concreate it would be great.